# Wordpress: post tag count doesn't increase after using wp_add_post_tags

Tags: wordpress

I'm using `wp_add_post_tags($post_id = 0, $tags = '')` function to add tags to a post.

When I do `wp_add_post_tags($post_id, 'new_tag')`, a new term is added to 'post_tags' taxonomy terms list.
I expect that the term count will be 1. However the count of that term is 0, even though I get the term when I do `wp_get_post_tags($post_id)` .

Any ideas why?

**EDIT:**
Is it possible that this behavior is because my post has a custom post_type?
--No, I checked it. It has nothing to do with the post_type.

Comment: How are you getting the term count?

Comment: @BridgetArrington I can see it in the terms list of the taxonomy in wp-admin, but I already used a custom taxonomy, and it works fine with it. Still don't know what was the problem there..